# Symfony: append YAML settings instead of override

Tags: view, symfony1, settings, yaml

In symfony's `view.yml` i can set the stylesheets in this way:

```
(in frontend/config/view.yml)

stylesheets: [main, second]
```

What if i wanted to add stylesheets to a specific module, without changing the default ones? so instead of writing this line:

```
(in frontend/modules/mymodule/config/view.yml)

stylesheets: [main, second, third]
```

I could write something like this:

```
(in frontend/modules/mymodule/config/view.yml)

stylesheets: [..., third]
```

This way I can change the default stylesheets for all the modules, and don't have to change it one by one.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will override the `stylesheets` definitions stored on the app level.

But you could do one of the following:

- Add a stylesheet to a specific template - add the following to your template file:

  ```
  <?php use_stylesheet('third') ?>
  ```
- Add a stylesheet to all templates of a module - add the following to your `actions.class.php`:

  ```
  public function preExecute()
  {
    parent::preExecute();
    $this->getResponse()->addStylesheet('third');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use «all» instead of «default» in your module's view.yml or it will override the default view configuration defined in the application.